# Pyspark: how to read a csv file with timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a .csv table like the folloiwng

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv')
df.head(3)

```
            identifier                 identifier_type         timestamp           device_lat   device_lon
0   68d62a1b-b928-4225-b445-9607415905b3    gaid         2020-03-19 03:03:00 UTC    44.808169   -73.522956
1   1675a629-a010-44b6-98a9-72d04793821f    gaid         2020-03-18 21:15:42 UTC    42.103894   -76.799164
2   0fe7a0b7-028e-459e-b5d8-b59d31800b8e    gaid         2020-03-18 23:39:54 UTC    43.182028   -77.672017
```

I am reading it with `pyspark`

```
schema= StructType([
        StructField("identifier", StringType(), True),
        StructField("identifier_type", StringType(), True),
        StructField("timestamp", DateType(), True),
        StructField("device_lat", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("device_lon", FloatType(), True)])

myTable = spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).load('NY_data/f0.csv') 
myTable = myTable[myTable['device_lat']>0]
myTable.show(3)

    +--------------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+
|          identifier|identifier_type| timestamp|device_lat|device_lon|
+--------------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+
|68d62a1b-b928-422...|           gaid|2020-03-19|  44.80817| -73.52296|
|1675a629-a010-44b...|           gaid|2020-03-18| 42.103893|-76.799164|
|0fe7a0b7-028e-459...|           gaid|2020-03-18|  43.18203| -77.67202|
+--------------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Why did the information of minutes, hour and seconds disappear?

If I try `TimestampType` type instead of `DateType`

```
schema= StructType([
        StructField("identifier", StringType(), True),
        StructField("identifier_type", StringType(), True),
        StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
        StructField("device_lat", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("device_lon", FloatType(), True)])

myTable = spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).load('NY_data/f0.csv') 
myTable = myTable[myTable['device_lat']>0]
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(myTable, "myTable")
```

This is what I get

```
myTable.show(3)
+----------+---------------+---------+----------+----------+
|identifier|identifier_type|timestamp|device_lat|device_lon|
+----------+---------------+---------+----------+----------+
+----------+---------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

The type of variables are.

```
df.dtypes
identifier          object
identifier_type     object
timestamp           object
device_lat         float64
device_lon         float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: @AlexW I tried but I get empty values as you can see in the modified question

Comment: What does `df.dtypes` look like?

Comment: @AlexW I added the information

Comment: Can you try `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].copy(), infer_datetime_format=True)` and see if it yields a better result?

Comment: @AlexW now it gives `timestamp          datetime64[ns, UTC]` but I would like to read it directly in pyspark.

Comment: see below update to my answer, I am wondering if you need to explicitly set your timestamp format in pyspark

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210131/discussion-between-emax-and-alex-w).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely guessing, but I think you may need a [`TimestampType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/TimestampType.html) type instead of `DateType`.

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DateType.html) for `DateType` only mentions Month/Day/Year:

> A date type, supporting "0001-01-01" through "9999-12-31". Please use
>   the singleton DataTypes.DateType.
>
> Internally, this is represented as the number of days from epoch
>   (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).

According to [Pyspark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader), when using `spark.read()` you can specify the timestamp format:

> timestampFormat – sets the string that indicates a timestamp format.
>   Custom date formats follow the formats at `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.
>   This applies to timestamp type. If None is set, it uses the default
>   value, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`.  The default value looks like it's the ISO standard so if your CSV file has a different timestamp format it won't work without explicitly setting the correct format value.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader

So, if your timestamp CSV values are different than the default ISO 8601 standard format (e.g. `2020-03-22T21:51:29Z`), you would need to match whatever the CSV date/time format is to the corresponding `java.text.SimpleDate` format.  The date/time format characters are listed in the docs for Java:

For CSV values such as `2020-01-19 19:30:30 UTC` the date format string would be similar to: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss z`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html